# TextSecure Server (Signal) Configuration

Tags: java, maven, messenger

I have installed TextSecure (Signal) server tagged v0.93 at GitHub on CentOS 7. Compilation passed ok, jars are in order, config is in order, however when I try to start it:

```
java -jar /Server/target/TextSecureServer-2.25.jar server /Server/config/server.yml &
```

it gives output:

```
INFO  [2019-02-10 19:03:15,113] io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory: Registering jersey handler with root path prefix: /
INFO  [2019-02-10 19:03:15,116] io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory: Registering admin handler with root path prefix: /
INFO  [2019-02-10 19:03:16,401] com.relayrides.pushy.apns.ApnsClientBuilder: Native SSL provider is available and supports ALPN; will use native provider.
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
        at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:89)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:158)
        at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.entities.MessageProtos$ServerCertificate.<init>(MessageProtos.java:2010)
        at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.entities.MessageProtos$ServerCertificate.<init>(MessageProtos.java:1974)
        at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.entities.MessageProtos$ServerCertificate$1.parsePartialFrom(MessageProtos.java:2062)
        at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.entities.MessageProtos$ServerCertificate$1.parsePartialFrom(MessageProtos.java:2057)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:137)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:168)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:180)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:185)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
        at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.entities.MessageProtos$ServerCertificate.parseFrom(MessageProtos.java:2648)
        at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.auth.CertificateGenerator.<init>(CertificateGenerator.java:28)
        at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.WhisperServerService.run(WhisperServerService.java:232)
        at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.WhisperServerService.run(WhisperServerService.java:102)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:87)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
        at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
        at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.WhisperServerService.main(WhisperServerService.java:292)
```

Seems like there is some problem with certificates somewhere. If i comment line in:

src/main/java/org/whispersystems/textsecuregcm/WhisperServerService.java:232

```
environment.jersey().register(new CertificateController(new CertificateGenerator(config.getDeliveryCertificate().getCertificate(), config.getDeliveryCertificate().getPrivateKey(), config.getDeliveryCertificate().getExpiresDays())));
```

it starts without problem.

Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following is the certificate generating steps figured out by myself.

Config "Unidentified Delivery" of Signal Server:

This feature is also known as Sealed Sender.
https://signal.org/blog/sealed-sender/

1.Generate CA key pair:
java -jar TextSecureServer-2.92.jar certificate --ca

It will print out Public key and Private key for CA.

2.Generate server certificate:
java -jar TextSecureServer-2.92.jar certificate --key XXX --id 2020

XXX is Private key for CA. id must be a number. 
It will print out Certificate and Private key for your server.

3.Fill the following YAML fields with your server Certificate and Private key:
unidentifiedDelivery:
    certificate: 
    privateKey:

Note: The CA certificate may also be needed by Signal Desktop/Android/iOS apps.

The above server certificate is loaded by the code here:
https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Server/blob/master/service/src/main/java/org/whispersystems/textsecuregcm/configuration/UnidentifiedDeliveryConfiguration.java

The code to generate the above CA cert and server cert:
https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Server/blob/master/service/src/main/java/org/whispersystems/textsecuregcm/workers/CertificateCommand.java

and finally if you find any config errors, you can always refer to the config-related code here:
https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Server/tree/master/service/src/main/java/org/whispersystems/textsecuregcm/configuration